# Actionscript if statement to include file if variable is true

Tags: actionscript, if-statement, actionscript-2

I am creating a script to include hard code and click tags for web advertising. Basically I'm trying to make the process easier by having all of my html links in one file, but controlled with if statements.

So far it works fine, but I get kick backs from google/aol/yahoo because when they go through the swf they see these other html links, even though they are not being used, and kick back the banner.

I'm trying now to include two files, one with hard codes, and another with just click tags. And if a variable is true, include the hardcode file, if not ignore it. The syntax makes sense to me, but is throwing an error in flash still. Is there a better way of going about this?

Here is my code:

```
on(release){    
    var video = "false";
    var hardclicktags = "false"

    #include "_clicktags.as"

    if( hardclicktags == "true" ){
        #include "_hardtags.as"
    };


}
```

This works fine if _hardtags.as is present in the file, but because of google/yahoo/aol still reading the other if statements I can't have any other html links inside of the file. So I would remove my _hardtags.as from the folder before I publish. But this is throwing an error saying it can't find the file. To me though, because hardclicktags = "false" it should ignore this line all together.

Is there a way around this, or am I kind of stuck going about this a different way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For now I'm including the _hardtags.as inside of my _clicktags.as file and when it's not needed I'm just commenting it out.

Comment: I don't think AS2 offered conditional compilation, and I think if you want to use it in AS3, you'd have to use Flex.